# How do i format Oracle Output for this Block?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I'm stuck on this block of statements and don't know how to program the output when the code runs to show the amount of the payment as $10.00 and the balance remaining in  the same format. My code also prompts me twice for idpledge... I've got some markup in the code for topics I don't quite understand. Using Oracle 11g 2e and the book isn't very helpful. If there is a recommendation for beginner books or resources I am listening (reading). Code is below:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  pay_num           NUMBER(2) := 0; /*initialize to 0 */
  loop_count        NUMBER(2) := 12; /*intialize to max number of months */
  pay_amt           NUMBER(8,2);
  pledge_bal        NUMBER(8,2);
  v_pledgeamt       NUMBER(8,2);
  start_date        DATE := '04-OCT-2012';
  due_date      DATE;
  v_due_date        VARCHAR2(15);

BEGIN

  SELECT pledgeamt INTO v_pledgeamt
  FROM DD_PLEDGE
  WHERE idpledge=&idpledge;

  pay_amt := (v_pledgeamt / loop_count);
  due_date := start_date;
  pledge_bal := (v_pledgeamt - pay_amt);

  FOR i IN 1..loop_count LOOP

    pay_num := pay_num + 1;
    v_due_date := TO_CHAR(due_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
    due_date := add_months(due_date, 1);
    pledge_bal := (pledge_bal - pay_amt);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
      'Payment Num: ' || pay_num
      || ' ' || 'Due Date: ' || v_due_date
      || ' ' || 'Amount Due: ' || pay_amt  
      || ' ' || 'Balance: ' || TO_CHAR(pledge_bal, '$')); /* how to format with $*/

  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Data-Type/Usetocharsal999999toformatanumbertypecolumntocurrencyformat.htm

Comment: 'Balance: $' || to_char(pledge_bal)

Comment: Awesome! Don't know why but i was fervent the answer was (pledge_bal, '$5,000'); This works and now I can move on. Appreciate the link as well....Thanks!

Comment: You should use the mask provided in the link by @OldProgrammer in your case should be; to_char(pledge_bal, '$9,999.99')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned at [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510) you can use the to_char with a proper formatter. In your case it would be `to_char(pledge_bal, '$9,999.99')`
Using the format as ***'$9,999.99'*** fulfills the following objectives :

- Returns a comma in the specified position. You can specify multiple commas in a number format model.
- Returns a decimal point, which is a period (.) in the specified position.
- Returns value with a leading dollar sign.

If required you can check for more parameters at the link mentioned.